# How can I start publishing my library into python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, libraries

I would like to know how I can publish my library into the python server-side collection of libraries. If you know how to do it please let me know, such as making a comment into my question or making your own answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: does this help: https://pypi.org/help/#publishing?

Comment: Here's a good video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEFkHEKypLI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow Python's guide on [Packaging Projects](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

This includes

- How to structure a package
- How to install a package locally
- How to upload a package to PyPi

In packaging a library / module you can select classifiers relevent to your code's intended purpose, such as:

`Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: HTTP Servers`
if you want your program to be
run on servers

You can also look into `Environment ::` tags to see if you find anything that matches your requirements,
Besides that - so long as it isn't critical - you can always publish an untagged package, however I wouldn't reccomend this.

**Also see:**

[PyPi Publishing Guide](https://pypi.org/help/#publishing)